# jQuery click(false) combined with a function

Tags: jquery, function, click, default

I want to prevent the "#" from being used because I'm using jQuery to do something else with a plugin on click...

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">My Link</a>

<script>
    $('#mylink').somePlugin().click(false);
</script>
```

The above works nicely whenever I've needed to block the default click.

Now I have something like this below and I want to prevent the default click behavior

```
<a href="#" id="mylink">My Link</a>

$('#mylink').click( function () {
    //  my code in here
});
```

I'm just not sure where/how to incorporate click(false) into the code above.  Several things I've tried didn't work.

I know... I feel like a newbie asking this one.

Thank-you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do:

```
$('#mylink').click( function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // the code here
    });
```

Comment: I was using that but thought there was just a way to incorporate the click(false).  Thank-you!

Comment: There is no need to incorporate click false, preventDefault is a standards compliant function for this purpose, and used within jQuery benefits from its cross-browser compatability insurances (to as great a degree as all jQuery funcitonality), so there is no need to use anything else, apart from, as was pointed out, stopPropagation to stop the event from bubbling up, i.e. if you show a hidden nested ul, the parent li will also be shown (if hidden).

Comment: can you give a brief introduction to click(false)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#mylink').click( function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); is the correct way. if you return false you stop the event bubbling also.

Comment: @Am I know. Somebody downvoted you, and I was asking why. (I voted it back up)

Comment: I did not down-vote either but I was reading about why not to use "return false" here... http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: @Bjarki `return false` is also acceptable. It is shorter and doesn't require you to specify the event object as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

Different browsers handle this in slightly different ways, but jQuery does its best to cover your bases. There are three things you should know about, and at least the first two of them should be done to prevent normal click behavior in as many browsers as possible:

1. `return false;` at the end of your click handler (as Am [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286206/jquery-clickfalse-combined-with-a-function/5286224#5286224)) will stop the regular click action on a link in many browsers, including Internet Explorer and Google Chrome. `return false;` will also stop event propagation, which may or may not be what you wish. This is regular browser behavior, and does not have anything to do with jQuery.
2. `e.preventDefault();`, as [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286206/jquery-clickfalse-combined-with-a-function/5286212#5286212) by Liam is a [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) that prevents the default action to be triggered. *"For example, clicked anchors will not take the browser to a new URL."* This affects only the *current item*.
3. `e.stopPropagation();` is another [jQuery method](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) that prevents an event from bubbling. For example, if you have an anchor in a div, and the div has a click event hooked to it, the div's click event will be triggered even though you stop the anchors - unless you call this method.

Number 2 will cover almost all browsers, and with a combination of 1 and 2 you cover more or less all of them. Number 3 is only necessary if you don't want the event to bubble in the DOM tree, but I make it a habit to have it there, since mostly if I want to prevent the default action on a clicked element, I don't want *anything* except the code in *this specific handler* to happen.

Comment: @Thomas `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` are not jQuery methods, but they are defined by the [DOM Events standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#interface-Event) (they have been around for quite some time). Note that jQuery normalizes the events object, so that those two methods will work in all browsers.

Comment: Yes- very good explanation.  So where does .click(false) fit into all this?  I was hoping that by using that, I'd just be letting jQuery handle it.

Comment: @Sparky `click(false)` doesn't fit into this at all. Don't use it. The `click` method should either have no arguments or a function argument. Don't pass the `false` value into it.

Comment: @Šime Vidas -  I got click(false) from a jQuery plugin developer who said it's ok to use with jQuery above version 1.4.2.  Do you have any further reference I can read on that?

Comment: @Šime: You said it yourself: jQuery normalizes the event object, and thus they are methods defined by jQuery on an object defined by jQuery. The fact that they have the same names as the original methods in some javascript engines is another matter ;)

Comment: @Sparky The jQuery documentation does not mention passing boolean values into event binding methods. It may work in 1.4 and 1.5 but that doesn't mean that it will work in the future. Read about the click method here: http://api.jquery.com/click/